# Are there external graphics files with natural depth?

Tags: graphics

The `\includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` package provides options `height` and `totalheight` for resizing embedded graphics.

As long as the graphics file doesn't possess a natural depth, it doesn't make a difference whether the one or the other option is used.

Therefore I wonder why `totalheight` is provided at all. Are there graphics file formats that allow for natural depth? I have never met one so far, but I am willing to accept the contrary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The keys are interpreted in order so after

```
angle=180, height=3in
```

it first flips the image upside down so it's all in the depth, then tries to scale the 0pt height to 3in....

The first release didn't have a `totalheight` key, I added one pretty quickly:-)

You are probably correct that the external images in general don't naturally have a depth but the package doesn't assume that: if there was an image format with a natural baseline specification as well as total size, a `graphicx` driver could import that into latex with natural height and depth.

Comment: Thank you! I completely disregarded the case of rotation prior to resizing. Now `totalheight` makes sense, indeed.